# illegal arument exception in ajax call while passing js array object

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am passing two variables in ajax call, one as normal string variable and other one js array object which i m sending to my java class..but when i m sending with array object,the ajax call is getting failed and throwing 500 response code with illegal argument exception

```
var array1 = new Array();
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    array1.push($(inputs[i]).attr('name').toString());
}

var path = "javaclassurl";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: path,
    data: {
        var1: var1,
        array1: array1
    },

});
$(this).dialog("close");
//}

},
```

This is the way i m receiving in my java class

```
String values[]=request.getParameterValues("array1");
```

This ajax call is inside dialog box as its a dialog box plugin being used.Please help me in getting the error corrected

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try doing it this way:
    String values[]=request.getParameterValues("array1[]");

Answer (score 0):

jQuery API documentation for .ajax() call states:

> processData (default: true)
>   Type: Boolean
>   By default, data passed in to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false.

So you might try setting this to false.